# Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'create'

Tags: backbone.js

Why am I getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'create' "

I have tried to stay close to this [backbone todo example code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html).

http://jsfiddle.net/GhaPF/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ToDo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: { "date": "today",
                    "task": ""
                },
        initialize: function() {}
    });

    var ToDoList = Backbone.Model.extend({
        model: ToDo
    });

    var ToDoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        initialize: function(myTodoList) {
            this.todolist = myTodoList;
            this.todolist.bind('change', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            text = this.todolist.toJSON();
            string = JSON.stringify(text);
            $(this.el).append(string);
            return this;
        },
        events: {
            "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter"
        },
        createOnEnter: function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
          if (!$("#new-todo").val()) return;
          this.todolist.create({"task": $("#new-todo").val()});
          $("#new-todo").val('');
        }
    });

    var todolist = new ToDoList();
    var myToDoListView = new ToDoListView(todolist);

});
```

---

I had two mistakes in there:

1. defined ToDoList as a Model instead of a Collection
2. used save() instead of add() on the collection, this triggered the hunt for a URL which did not exist

Here is a working code for what I wanted to achieve here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ToDo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: { "date": "today",
                    "task": ""
                },
        initialize: function() {}
    });

    var ToDoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ToDo
    });

    var ToDoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        initialize: function(myTodoList) {
            this.todolist = myTodoList;
            this.todolist.bind('add', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            text = this.todolist.toJSON();
            string = JSON.stringify(text);
            $(this.el).append(string);
            return this;
        },
        events: {
            "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter"
        },
        createOnEnter: function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
          if (!$("#new-todo").val()) return;
          this.todolist.add({"task": $("#new-todo").val()});
          //this.render();
          $("#new-todo").val('');
        }
    });

    var todolist = new ToDoList();
    var myToDoListView = new ToDoListView(todolist);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is because your `ToDoList` is extending Backbone.Model. It should be extending Backbone.Collection.

Here's the code to fix it.

```
var ToDoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: ToDo,
  url: '/todos' 
});
```

Comment: Ah correct! Thanks. But now I have another error: "Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified".  http://jsfiddle.net/GhaPF/5/

Comment: Since the create function saves the model to the server, you have to add the url propert to the collection so it knows what url to call on the server to add a model. See the url documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url

Comment: Thank you! I confused save() with add().